# Positive harmonic function with harmonic reciprocal must be constant

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $f(z)$ be a positive harmonic function on the unit disk such that $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is also harmonic. Show $f(z)$ must be constant.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/572904/37122

Comment: @BenjaminDickman I don't think this question is a duplicate since the OP only assumes that $f$ is harmonic on the unit disk, not the whole space.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. the answer (at least the one we can access) in the linked question doesn't cover this case at all.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $0=\Delta(f\cdot 1/f)=f\Delta(1/f)+2\langle \nabla f,\nabla(1/f) \rangle+\Delta(f)(1/f).$

Comment: When I saw this question, I computed $\Delta(1/f)$, then derived $|\nabla f|^2=0$, but this is cleaner (but hints usually are, avoiding a lot of the messy part). +1

Answer (score 3):

A different (I think more elegant) approach: $\displaystyle \pi r^2=\int_{B(0,r)}1=\int_{B(0,r)}\frac{\sqrt{f}}{\sqrt{f}}\le\bigg(\int_{B(0,r)}f\bigg)^{1/2}\bigg(\int_{B(0,r)}\frac{1}{f}\bigg)^{1/2}=\pi r^2\frac{\sqrt{f}}{\sqrt{f}}=\pi r^2\,,$ hence we must have equality in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality so that $\displaystyle \sqrt{f}=\frac{c}{\sqrt{f}}\,,$ so $f=c\,.$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}(\frac{1}{f})=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(-\frac{f_x}{f^2})=-\frac{f_{xx}}{f^2}+2\frac{f_x^2}{f^3}.$$
This implies that 
$$\tag{1}\Delta (1/f)=(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2})(\frac{1}{f})=-\frac{f_{xx}+f_{yy}}{f^2}+2\frac{f_x^2+f_y^2}{f^3}
=-\frac{\Delta f}{f^2}+2\frac{f_x^2+f_y^2}{f^3}.$$
Since $f$ and $1/f$ are both harmonic, $\Delta (1/f)=\Delta f=0$, which implies by $(1)$ that 
$$2\frac{f_x^2+f_y^2}{f^3}=0,$$ or equivalently, 
$$f_x^2+f_y^2=0$$
which implies that $f$ is constant.