# Show that a nonnegative harmonic function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f(z): \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is harmonic and that $f(z) \ge 0 $ for all complex $z$.  Then $f$ must be constant.

I imagine that I will need to make use of Liousville's theorem or otherwise show that $f'$ is zero.  However the problem is that the book has not mentioned anything about harmonic functions other then the definition that the second partials of the real and imaginary parts add to zero.  It is clear that an analytic function is harmonic from the Cauchy Riemann equations, is the converse true?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Compare [Positive harmonic function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a constant?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561818/positive-harmonic-function-on-mathbbrn-is-a-constant).

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is "harmonic conjugate" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_conjugate In short, yes, starting from a harmonic function you can build a holomorphic function.

Answer (score 5):

Let $u(x,y)$ be an harmonic non negative function. Then, exists an harmonic conjugate $v(x,y)$ such that $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ where $z=x+iy$ is analytic in $\mathbb{C}$.

Now, consider $e^{f(z)}$. This function is analytic as $e$ and $f$ are, is never zero, and $|e^{f(z)}|=e^u \geq 1 $ because $u \geq 0$. Then $\frac{1}{e^{f(z)}}$ is analytic and bounded so for Liouville's theorem, must be constant. In this way, $u$ must be constant too.