# Is $e^{u+v}$ a harmonic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Given $u$ and $v$ two harmonic functions, is it true that $e^{u+v}$ is a harmonic function?.

Using the Laplace equation for proving that $e^{u+v}$ is harmonic, I get:
Setting $I=e^{u+v}$
$$I_{xx}+I_{yy}=e^{u+v}\left[(u_{x}+v_{x})^2+(u_{y}+v_{y})^2+u_{xx}+u_{yy}+v_{xx}+v_{yy}\right]$$
It reduces to:
$$I_{xx}+I_{yy}=e^{u+v}\left[(u_{x}+v_{x})^2+(u_{y}+v_{y})^2\right]$$
my question is if this expression can be reduced to zero.
Thanks.

Comment: A sum of squares is zero very rarely, and $\exp(u+v)$ is always positive...

Comment: Let $u(x,y) = x, v(x,y)=0.$ Then both $u,v$ are harmonic, but $e^{u+v} =e^x,$ hence $\Delta e^{u+v} =e^x,$ which is never $0.$

Answer (score 7):

If $u,v$ are harmonic functions then $u+v$ is a harmonic function too, and we just need to prove (or **disprove**) that the exponential map sends harmonic functions into harmonic functions. We have:
$$ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} e^{f(x,y)} = e^{f(x,y)}\left[\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\right],\quad \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} e^{f(x,y)} = e^{f(x,y)}\left[\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)^2+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\right]$$
hence
$$ \Delta e^{f(x,y)} = e^{f(x,y)}\left[\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)^2\right]$$
which equals zero only if $f$ is constant.

Comment: Thank you Jack. I get the same conclusion.