# Exercise Jurgen Jost's PDE show that u harmonic and nonnegative is constant

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

**2.5: Let u be harmonic and nonnegative, show that u is constant**. (Hint use the previous exercise).

The previous exercise was posted in another question, stated the following.

**2.4: Let $u:B(0,R)\subset \mathbb{R^d}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be harmonic and nonnegative. Prove the following version of the Harnack inequality**: $$\dfrac{R^{d-2}(R-|x|)}{(R+|x|)^{d-1}}u(0)\leq u(x)\leq \dfrac{R^{d-2}(R+|x|)}{(R-|x|)^{d-1}}u(0)$$

I used the poisson's integral for the ball that states the following.

$$u(x)=\dfrac{R^2-|x|}{n\alpha(n)R}\int_{\partial B(0,R)}\dfrac{g(y)}{|x-y|^n}dS(y)$$
and the fact that for $y\in \partial B(0,R)$, $|y|=R$ and $|x|-|y|\leq |x-y|\leq |x|+|y|$ that is $|x|-R\leq |x-y|\leq |x|+R$.

Any hints on how to apply 2.4 to 2.5? thanks in advance.

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561818/positive-harmonic-function-on-mathbbrn-is-a-constant

Answer (score 1):

Just let $R\to\infty$. Both sides of the inequality converge to $u(0)$.